# Vertically center text across two rows

Tags: vertical-alignment, multirow

I'm using the "calc2latex" macro for OpenOffice Calc to easily create tables. However it doesn't always work perfectly. In this case, I created the following table, but the texts in the two multirows of the fifth column aren't vertically aligned. Do you have an idea how to fix that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{111} & \textbf{222} & \textbf{333} & \textbf{444} & \textbf{555} & \textbf{666} \\ \hline 
&  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{eee} & fff \\ \cline{ 1- 4}\cline{ 6- 6}
aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & fff \\ \hline &  &  &  & &  \\ \hline
aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{eee} & fff \\ \cline{ 1- 4}\cline{ 6- 6}
aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & fff \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no \multirow in the fifth column, only a `\multicolumn`, which works horizontally.

Comment: This is a problem of calc2latex which does not implement multirow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need  `\multirow{2}{*}{content}` to substitute the \multicolumn environment.  Thanks to @Mico.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{caption}
\label{}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{111} & \textbf{222} & \textbf{333} & \textbf{444} & \textbf{555} & \textbf{666} \\ 
\hline 
&  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & \multirow{2}{*}{eee} & fff \\ 
\cline{ 1- 4}\cline{ 6- 6}
aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd &  & fff \\ 
\hline 
&  &  &  & &  \\ \hline
aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & \multirow{2}{*}{eee} & fff \\ 
\cline{ 1- 4}\cline{ 6- 6}
aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd &  & fff \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to encase the `\multirow` statements in `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{...}` statements. Likewise, the `\multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{}` statements can be replaced with blank space.

Comment: @Mico -- Thanks for the comment. Somehow, I learned the skill from here, so kind of addict to it.